# How to set context root of a web app using spring 4.1 using annotations

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I am trying to set up a simple web app using spring annotations. I am referring to sample projects given in spring site. Can anyone let me know how can I set the context root to below given example?

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-web/tree/master/6/complete.

I can build it locally and access it as `http://localhost:8080/`

I want to access it like `http://localhost:8080/spring`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in the same build file. We need to set

```
tomcatRunWar.contextPath = 'spring'
```

in *build.gradle*